# Display 2 tables in 1 view laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display 2 variables in one view

{{ $match->title }} and {{ $distance->unit }}

but only the $match is working while the $distance returns null when I dd(); it.

I have tried doing this but the $distances still gives me null

```
 $matches = BikeGame::find($request->id);
 $distances = Distance::find($request->id);
```

```
$matches = BikeGame::where('id',$request->id)->first();
$distances = Distance::where('id',$request->id)->first();
```

```
$matches = BikeGame::find($request->get('id'));
$distances = Distance::find($request->get('id'));
```

My BikeGame Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BikeGame extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function distances(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Distance');   
   }

}
```

My Distance Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Distance extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function bikegames(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\BikeGame');
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
public function bikeGamesMatch(Request $request){ 
    $matches = BikeGame::find($request->id);
    $distances = Distance::find($request->id);
    dd($distances);
    return view('bike_games.match', compact("matches","distances"));
}
```

I want my view to display this

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Game Title:</strong>
    @foreach($matches as $match)
      {{ $match->title }}
    @endforeach
</th>

<th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Target: Distance</strong>
    @foreach($distances as $distance) 
       {{ $distance->distance }} {{ $distance->unit }}
    @endforeach
</th>
```

Comment: In DB, `distances` table has the record include same ID with `bikegames` table ?

Comment: Please check your table to see if the record you're looking for corresponding to the request ID actually exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the relation you defined in the model.

In your controller:

```
public function bikeGamesMatch(Request $request) 
{ 
    $match = BikeGame::find($request->id); // note is just one object

    return view('bike_games.match', compact("match"));
}
```

and in blade

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center">
    <strong>Game Title:</strong>
    {{ $match->title }}
</th>

<th scope="col" class="text-center">
    <strong>Target: Distance</strong>
    @foreach($match->distances as $distance) 
       {{ $distance->distance }} {{ $distance->unit }}
    @endforeach
</th>
```

---

**EDIT**

**BikeGame Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BikeGame extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function distance(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Distance', 'distance_id');   
   }

}
```

**Distance Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Distance extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function bikegames(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\BikeGame'); // this could be hasOne, depending on if you are going to use the same distance for other games or not
    }

}
```

**Controller**:

```
public function bikeGamesMatch(Request $request){ 
    $match = BikeGame::find($request->id);

    return view('bike_games.match', compact("match"));
}
```

**View** `bike_games/match.blade.php`

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Game Title:</strong>
    {{ $match->title }}
</th>

<th scope="col" class="text-center"><strong>Target: Distance</strong>
    @isset($match->distance)
    {{ $match->distance->distance }} {{ $match->distance->unit }}
    @endisset
</th>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194471/discussion-on-answer-by-porloscerros--display-2-tables-in-1-view-laravel).

Comment: If its okay, can you also explain this code?  {{ $match->distance->distance }} {{ $match->distance->unit }}  what does ->distance mean? the first ->distance